# Warning: ftp_get(): Delete operation successful

Tags: php, ftp

I've got a bit of code that transfers backups from our development servers, and it randomly seems to behave very strangely and giving the following errors/output:

```
Warning: ftp_get(): Delete operation successful. in /root/cron/get_dev_archives.php on line 106
ERR blahjob: Failed to get file: 2013-09-25_18-22-04-blahjob_dev18.tgz
PHP Warning:  ftp_get(): Delete operation successful. in /root/cron/get_dev_archives.php on line 106

Warning: ftp_get(): Delete operation successful. in /root/cron/get_dev_archives.php on line 106
ERR blahjob: Failed to get file: 2013-09-25_18-22-37-blahjob_dev19.tgz
PHP Warning:  ftp_get(): Delete operation successful. in /root/cron/get_dev_archives.php on line 106

Warning: ftp_get(): Delete operation successful. in /root/cron/get_dev_archives.php on line 106
ERR blahjob: Failed to get file: 2013-09-25_18-23-05-blahjob_dev5.tgz
PHP Warning:  ftp_get(): Delete operation successful. in /root/cron/get_dev_archives.php on line 106

Warning: ftp_get(): Delete operation successful. in /root/cron/get_dev_archives.php on line 106
ERR blahjob: Failed to get file: 2013-09-25_18-23-37-blahjob_dev33.tgz
```

I haven't the slightest idea what delete has to do with `ftp_get()`, or why it's returning `false` and throwing a warning about another operation's success. Google has also been unhelpful in finding any similar issues.

Code in question:

```
// ftp connection established, file list acquired, yadda yadda
foreach( $targets as $target ) {
    $localfile = $backup_dir . $target;
    if( file_exists($localfile) ) {
        do_log($task['name'], "Local file ".$target." already exists, skipping.", 1);
        continue;
    }
    if( ! ftp_get($conn, $localfile, $target, FTP_BINARY) ) { // line 106
        do_log($task['name'], "Failed to get file: ".$target, 2);
    } else {
        do_log($task['name'], "Got file: ".$target);
        ftp_delete($conn, $target);
    }
}
```

Comment: What server setup are you using? The local, where this php script is running.

Comment: @wumm CentOS 5.7 server running PHP 5.2.10, this script runs via CLI/cron.

Comment: Can you show they array with your targets? And were do you define `$task['name']`>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my opinion you are incurring in a strange PHP bug.

The `Delete operation successful.` is not a PHP error message, it's the FTP server response message for a successful delete (DELE) command.

After an analysis of the PHP source code, the only explanation I can find for this problem is that the `ftp_get` function is failing without getting an error message from the FTP server, therefore it's displaying the FTP server response of the previous executed command which, in this specific case, is a delete command.

The PHP FTP functions store the FTP server response text in the [inbuf field](https://github.com/frice2014/php_source/blob/master/ext/ftp/ftp.h#L63) of the `ftpbuf` structure:

```
typedef struct ftpbuf {
    ...
    char        inbuf[FTP_BUFSIZE]; /* last response text */
    ...
}
```

Such field is then used in the [ftp_get function](https://github.com/frice2014/php_source/blob/master/ext/ftp/php_ftp.c#L902) to display the warning message:

```
if (!ftp_get(ftp, outstream, remote, xtype, resumepos TSRMLS_CC)) {
    php_stream_close(outstream);
    VCWD_UNLINK(local);
    php_error_docref(NULL TSRMLS_CC, E_WARNING, "%s", ftp->inbuf);
    RETURN_FALSE;
}
```

The `ftp->inbuf` field is written by the [ftp_getresp fnc](https://github.com/frice2014/php_source/blob/master/ext/ftp/ftp.c#L1194), but it may be that, for some obscure reason, the low level [ftp_get function](https://github.com/frice2014/php_source/blob/master/ext/ftp/ftp.c#L788) is failing without calling the `ftp_getresp` function, therefore showing a misleading error message.
Maybe the FTP server error logs could give some clues about what the real problem is, but without further informations is really difficult to say **why** you're experiencing this problem and even to propose a workaround.

My only suggestion is to test your code (if possible) against a different FTP server, then eventually upgrade your PHP to a newer version.

Comment: Yep. I was thinking about your response and considering that maybe the FTP connection gets dropped, and the 'Delete operation successful' is just the last message in the buffer. I was looking in to sending a NOOP to check the connection between downloads when I found [this PHP bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60183) about the matter which *says* it's fixed as of 5.3.8, but then there's also [this one](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52766) which implies it still exists. Go PHP devs. :/