# copy files from one server to another using php

Tags: php, file, ftp, transfer

I have two similar websites.Some of the content are same in both sites.I have some files in specific folder in one website say A.I want to copy some specific files from Website A to website B.

I have tried ftp functions in php but not working.

```
 <?php

// define some variable

$local_file = 'eg.html';

$server_file = 'http://example.com/horoscope/M12459TAM_03092009_123239.html';

// set up basic connection

$conn_id = ftp_connect("example.com");


// login with username and password

$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, 'username', 'password');

echo is_array(ftp_nlist($conn_id, ".")) ? 'Connected!' : 'not Connected! :(';

ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

// try to download $server_file and save to $local_file

if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {

    echo "Successfully written to $local_file\n";

} else {

    echo "There was a problem\n";

}
// close the connection

ftp_close($conn_id);


?>
```

I get connected message but display "There was a problem".Pls can anyone try this..

Regards,
Rekha

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19034026/warning-ftp-get-delete-operation-successful) may be helpful

Comment: I cant able to understand your answer.

Comment: I think there is issue in server path.Can anyone tell me whether the server path is correct or not

Comment: Why not try *rsync* for this task, unless you really need to do this in php.  FTP passes passwords in the clear, unless you are transferring locally, you really do not want to use that.

Comment: @RekhaPrabhu yes, your server path must point to a local path in remote server when you get connected, not a url. If you want to get a file from a public file on a web server like yourn server path you can use wget with exec() php function or file_get_contents()

Answer (score 0):

change last part where `ftp_get` to `ftp_put`

```
if (ftp_put($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {

    echo "Successfully written to $local_file\n";

} else {

    echo "There was a problem\n";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your $server_file path, I think you must point to the local file in your remote server.

For example:

```
/some_directory/horoscope/M12459TAM_03092009_123239.html
```

Instead of the URL form of the file.

Answer (score -1):

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('IP address', Port_No);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'server_username', 'server_password');
ssh2_scp_send($connection,'File_Path','Destination_Path', 0644);
```